# SwiftUI 2,s Mapkit MKPointOfInterestFilter

Tags: swiftui, mapkit

Is there any way to filter the point of interest using SwiftUI 2 Mapkit View

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/map

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkmapview/3143417-pointofinterestfilter

I want to do something like this

```
let filter = MKPointOfInterestFilter(including: [.cafe])
mapView.pointOfInterestFilter = filter
```

But using the new

```
Map(coordinateRegion: <#T##Binding<MKCoordinateRegion>#>, 
interactionModes: <#T##MapInteractionModes#>, 
showsUserLocation: <#T##Bool#>, 
userTrackingMode: <#T##Binding<MapUserTrackingMode>?#>, 
annotationItems: <#T##RandomAccessCollection#>, 
annotationContent: <#T##(Identifiable) -> MapAnnotationProtocol#>)
```

Comment: Did you make any progress in this feature?

Comment: No I moved to something else, I was just playing around with SwiftUI at the time.